# Visual Studio C# HttpClient GET Request doesnt display textfile lines correctly

Tags: c#, httpclient

I'm having an issue with `HttpClient` in Visual Studio C#.

I was trying to make a `GetStringAsync` request with `HttpClient` but the response is not formatted as expected.

The request is like *phpfile.php?readmode=yes*, it displays the text file response but it is not formatted well as shown below:

```
hello
hello
```

but it displays:

```
hellohello
```

I searched the internet for almost 2 hours and I am still confused, here is the code

```
string url = URL;
var responseString = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
```

and then I am adding it to a textbox (as this is some kind of msg client):

```
f1.msglog.Text = f1.msglog.Text + Environment.NewLine + responseString.ToString();
```

Comment: Whatever is producing that string (i.e. the PHP code) is the problem. Look there.

Comment: @IanKemp The code was working when i was using WebRequest with the Stream reader so its not the php script`s fault, In fiddler the format is correct is just that the HttpClient is not displaying it correctly. P.S I switched to HttpClient because its more Reliable and its asynchronous so the client doesnt frooze

Comment: Then why did you not **include that information** in your question originally? Why didn't you include a screenshot of the Fiddler trace? Help us to help you by providing **all** the relevant information, not just bits and pieces.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "display"? Where are you displaying the text and has anything about it changed since it was working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be an issue with different types of line endings. Try standardizing the line endings with this:

```
responseString.Replace("\r\n", "\n").Replace("\r", "\n").Replace("\n", Environment.NewLine)
```

By the way, don't call ToString. This was already a string, so calling ToString does nothing.